# Why int x=08; is valid when int x=078; is invalid in `DMD`?

Tags: d, literals, octal, dmd

I was recently looking into the details of literals in the *D programming language*.

Because *octal literals* use `0` as prefix to the numbers, `int x = 078;` is invalid naturally. But then why `int x = 08;` is valid in *DMD*?

However, I have tested the same with *GCC* (C compiler) to find that both are invalid.

```d
import std.stdio;

int main(string[] args)
{
    // int x = 078; // error here: radix 8 digit expected, not '8'
    int x = 08; // but no error here
    writeln("x = ", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a bug in *DMD*?
Thanks in advance.

N.B. I am using *DMD32 D Compiler v2.071.2-b2 (Win32 version)*.

Comment: According to a comment on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/221800/153446 Ken Thompson intentionally made 08 and 09 work in B:   Quote from Thompson's B Manual section 4.1 Primary Expressions: "An octal constant is the same as a decimal constant except that it begins with a zero. It is then interpreted in base 8. Note that 09 (base 8) is legal and equal to 011. A character constant is represented by ' followed by one or two characters (possibly escaped) followed by another '. It has an rvalue equal to the value of the characters packed and right adjusted. "

Comment: Only thinks that are code or intended to be read as monospaced text should be out in code blocks, not names of things.

Answer (score 3):

Octal literals are [deprecated in D](https://dlang.org/deprecate.html#Octal%20literals), and should error out if used. The fact that `dmd` accepts `08` is indicative of a bug. If you do want to use octals, then use the template `std.conv.octal`

```d
void main()
{
    import std.conv : octal;
    //int a = octal!8; //Error
    int b = octal!7; //Fine
}
```

Comment: It can't be a bug if it's not on Bugzilla! I quickly [filled](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16396) it.